# Recording and playing byte list in pyaudio/wave

Tags: python, wave, looper, pyaudio

I want to record and play my voice using pyaudio and wave lib but I don't know how to do it because wave lib requires a path to a file and even if I'm trying to set it as a variable with list of bytes recorded a few second ago, still doesn't work beacuse I can't use 'read' for a list. Does someone have some idea? I want to make a looper like KORG stuff, etc

I want to play it immediately after stopped recording, like real looper, without saving record as file.

There is my code (Python 3.4):

```
def record(self): #recording a voice

    #var for bytes from recording
    self.stream = self.player.open(format = self.FORMAT,
            channels = self.CHANNELS,
            rate = self.RATE,
            input = True,
            frames_per_buffer = self.CHUNK)

    print("Recording")

    self.frames = [] #byte list

    #recoring for a few seconds (5sec at this moment)
    for i in range(0, int(self.RATE / self.CHUNK * self.RECORD_SECONDS)):
        self.data = self.stream.read(self.CHUNK) #sing stream do data var
        self.frames.append(self.data) #add bytes to the end of a list
    print("Stop recording")

    self.stopRecording()

def stopRecording(self):

    self.stream.stop_stream()
    self.stream.close()
    print("Recording has been stopped")

    self.play()

def play(self): #playing a record
    print("Playing")


    f = wave.open(self.frames,"rb")  
    #read data  
    data = f.readframes(CHUNK)  

    #play stream  
    while data != '':  
        self.stream.write(data)  
        data = f.readframes(CHUNK)  

    self.stopPlaying()
```

Comment: you get any error ?? a quick look say me that you not need it  `f = wave.open(self.frames,"rb")`

Comment: But how should I `readframes` from this list? It's yelling that `'list' has no attribute 'wave'` or no `read` attribute (whatever I'm trying to do)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After stop your record you need join your appended data, use `data = ''.join(self.frames)`, and at the end build a loop (for, while) to stream all your byte list, here is how i did:

```
import pyaudio

chunk = 1024
FORMAT = pyaudio.paInt16
CHANNELS = 1
RATE = 41000
RECORD_SECONDS = 5


p = pyaudio.PyAudio()

stream = p.open(format = FORMAT,
    channels = CHANNELS,
    rate = RATE,
    input = True,
    output = True,
    frames_per_buffer = chunk)



print ("***Recording***")

all = [] 

for i in range(0, RATE / chunk * RECORD_SECONDS):
     data = stream.read(chunk)
     all.append(data) 


print("***Stop recording***")


print ("***START PLAY***")


data = ''.join(all)


for i in range(0, len(data), chunk):
    stream.write(data[i:i+chunk])
```

Comment: I can't run your code, there is an error with float to int (you missed `int`, should be 
`for i in range(0, int(RATE / chunk * RECORD_SECONDS)):`
but I have another error
`Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "looptest.py", line 40, in <module>
    data = ''.join(all)
TypeError: sequence item 0: expected str instance, bytes found`

Comment: here my python27, and i can run normally

Comment: I have python 3.4, maybe that's the reason :D I should mention at the begenning which version I'm using

Comment: try `data = ''.join(all).strip('\0x0')`

Comment: Same error like before (with both codes, your and mine)

Comment: try this in your python 3.4 `data = ''.join(map(str, all))`

Comment: I fixed it with `b''.join(self.frames)` but your code works also, thanks :)
Your whole code works great now :) Now I have to fix mine because it still throws some errors but I think I'm close :D